# unable to setup nameserver in CentOS 5.8

Tags: centos, bind, nameserver

I have a VPS, which I'm trying to run **a** website on it and I want it to act as its own nameserver too. But so far, the domain doesn't resolve. Here's what I've done so far:

first of all, in my domain panel, I've set the nameservers to ns1.kpaste.ir, ns2.kpaste.ir and for both I've set the IP of the server.( I sould mention that a while back, I had installed Kloxo, on this same server, and everything was fine, but then I reinstalled my OS, and don't wanna install any control panel(free) no more.).

On the server, I've install bind and configured. Here's the configurations:

```
options {
   directory "/var/named";
   dump-file "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
   statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";

  query-source address * port 53;
};

controls {
 inet 127.0.0.1 allow { localhost; } keys { rndckey; };
};

zone "localhost" IN {
   type master;
   file "localhost.zone";
   allow-update { none; };
};

zone "kpaste.ir" IN {
   type master;
   file "/var/named/kpaste.ir.zone";
   allow-update { none; };
};

zone "203.150.88.in-addr.arpa" IN {
   type master;
   file "/var/named/203.150.88.rev";
   allow-update { none; };
};

include "/etc/rndc.key";
```

/var/named/localhost.zone

```
$TTL    86400 ; 24 hours could have been written as 24h
$ORIGIN localhost.
; line below = localhost 1D IN SOA localhost root.localhost
@  1D  IN        SOA @  root (
                              2002022401 ; serial
                              3H ; refresh
                              15 ; retry
                              1w ; expire
                              3h ; minimum
                             )
@  1D  IN  NS @
   1D  IN  A  127.0.0.1
```

/var/named/kpaste.ir.zone

```
$TTL            86400
@                 IN SOA            kpaste.ir.  root.kpaste.ir. (
100     ; serial
1H  ; refresh
1M  ; retry
1W  ; expiry
1D )    ; minimum
@               IN NS           ns1.kpaste.ir.
@               IN NS           ns2.kpaste.ir.
@               IN A            88.150.203.70
ns1             IN A            88.150.203.70
ns2             IN A            88.150.203.70
@               IN MX   10  mail.kpaste.ir.
mail            IN A            88.150.203.70
WWW             IN A            88.150.203.70
```

/var/named/203.150.88.rev

```
$TTL    86400
@                 IN SOA          kpaste.ir.  info.kpaste.ir. (
100     ; serial
1H  ; refresh
1M  ; retry
1W  ; expiry
1D)     ; minimum
@                IN NS            ns1.kpaste.ir.
1                 IN PTR          binggo.kpaste.ir.
```

When I run `dig kpaste.ir` on the server(through ssh), I get this:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.3.6-P1-RedHat-9.3.6-20.P1.el5_8.6 <<>> kpaste.ir
;; global options:  printcmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 42162
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 2, ADDITIONAL: 2

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;kpaste.ir.         IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
kpaste.ir.      86400   IN  A   88.150.203.70

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
kpaste.ir.      86400   IN  NS  ns1.kpaste.ir.
kpaste.ir.      86400   IN  NS  ns2.kpaste.ir.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns1.kpaste.ir.      86400   IN  A   88.150.203.70
ns2.kpaste.ir.      86400   IN  A   88.150.203.70

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 88.150.203.70#53(88.150.203.70)
;; WHEN: Wed Sep 18 04:47:46 2013
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 111
```

But on my local machine, I get this:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.8.1-P1 <<>> kpaste.ir
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
mnvoh@myh:~$ dig kpaste.ir

; <<>> DiG 9.8.1-P1 <<>> kpaste.ir
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 2113
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;kpaste.ir.         IN  A

;; Query time: 559 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Wed Sep 18 11:27:16 2013
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 27
```

I should elaborate that I have added the proper hostnames, the first entry in front of 127.0.0.1 in /etc/hosts is kpaste.ir and the bind service starts without any erros but I have errors in /var/log/messages. You can view 'messages' here:

```
http://88.150.203.70/messages
```

It was too long to paste here. In the log it states that foo.bar.com is unreachable, but I can ping that address just alright.

Thanks for any help in advance :)

EDIT: result of iptables -Lnv

```
[root@kpaste public]# iptables -L -n -v
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
18811 1005K RH-Firewall-1-INPUT  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 RH-Firewall-1-INPUT  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 3778 packets, 308K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain RH-Firewall-1-INPUT (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   34  3496 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           icmp type 255 
    0     0 ACCEPT     esp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     ah   --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            224.0.0.251         udp dpt:5353 
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:631 
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:631 
  464 35080 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
    2   164 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:22 
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:80 
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:443 
    3   180 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:53 
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:25 
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:110 
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:143 
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:993 
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:995 
18308  966K REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

Comment: Honestly, just use your registrars DNS service it will be so much easier for you.

Comment: `network unreachable resolving 'ns2.lacnic.net/A/IN': 2001:500:2d::d#53` - You have IPv6 configured, but not properly routed?  `zone localhost/IN: loading master file localhost.zone: file not found` - The file is not found?  Put the file in the right place, or fix your path?  `/etc/named.conf:12: using specific query-source port suppresses port randomization and can be insecure.` - Do the needful.

Comment: Thanks iain, I appreciate it. Well, I'm checking that out right now, but the thing is, it's kinda personal now :D, you know. I used a third-party dns for a day, but doing so would be pleading defeated. I ain't wanna be no loser in this battle, yo ;)

Comment: Thanks Zoredache, I'll check out the things you pointed out, clear the log, and get back to you on it.

Comment: MNVOH, if you mouseover the down arrow, you'll see the popup "This question does not show any research effort, it is unclear or not useful".  Downvotes without eason may be assumed to be for that one.  I disagree with the downvoter, and have in fact upvoted this question, but the downvoter is entitled to his or her opinion, and the mouseover text shows what it may be presumed to be.

Comment: Thanks MadHatter, of course he's entitled to down voting, hell I've down voted a lot of people my self :) but all I'm saying is a comment about the reason would nice. Thanks again

Comment: Good for you for taking that attitude; all I'm saying is that a default reason is provided, and you may reasonably presume that it applies if no alternative is given.

Comment: That I'll do my friend :). As a matter of fact, considering the amount of articles on configuring bind, the down vote is reasonable, but what can I say, I just have a lot of road bump where ever I go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whilst I don't disagree with dsmsk80, I think you have more problems than just missing glue:

```
[me@risby ~]$ dig ns1.kpaste.ir @88.150.203.70

; <<>> DiG 9.9.3-rl.13207.22-P2-RedHat-9.9.3-5.P2.fc19 <<>> ns1.kpaste.ir @88.150.203.70
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

So I think you may have some firewall in place, or comparable issue, which is stopping the internet from reaching your new nameserver.

And on a parenthetical note, whilst I don't normally disagree with Iain, I think it *is* worth running your own nameserver.  You'll learn a lot of detail about how the DNS works by the time you have it running, and learning is always worthwhile.

**Edit**: you've only allowed TCP/53.  The DNS is primarily UDP-based, so you need to add an ACCEPT for inbound UDP with dport 53 as well.

Comment: The firewall is the reason, I've enabled `query-source address * port 53;` but I think I'll have to check to see if port 53 is allowed.

Comment: Oh, and by the way, I like your parethetical note ;) That's exactly why I'm doing all this. Otherwise I had the dns working flawlessly using cloadns.net

Comment: If the firewall does turn out to be the reason, don't forget to accept the answer; forgive my comment if you were going to do that anyway!

Comment: sure man :). Well it turns out it's not the problem. I opened port 53 in iptables, but nothing changed. I don't suppose that selinux has anything to do with it, does it?

Comment: I hesitate to quibble, but we get a **lot** of iptables questions on here, and some people do occasionally make mistakes in opening ports.  To knock the firewall out of the equation, could you paste the output of `iptables -L -n -v` into your question?

Comment: I posted the results. I guess it's ok, but I'll await your opinion on that. By the way, I remove /var/log/messages, and restarted the named service, but I ain't getting anything anymore in it!!

Comment: See new edit above.

Comment: Put simply, YOU ROCK MAN. I'd never thought of that myself. Thanks a million times. Although I vividly remember stopping iptables service and still not getting anything. I guess back then I didn't have the proper configuation. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You can verify your settings with freely available online DNS reporting tools such [viewdns.info](http://www.viewdns.info/dnsreport/). When I check your domain `kpaste.ir` I can see that there are missing correct glue records which would delegate the domain to your newly configured DNS servers.

[image]

To add a glue record for `kpaste.ir` you will need to contact your name registrar, as the glue records need to be created on the parent name servers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, dude. Well, I guess the changes have not been propagated yet. I have changed the nameservers and I'm sure the new ones have glue. But I'll definitely check out viewdns.info again in a few hours

Comment: The new ns is not available at viewdns.info. COuld you please check it out and see if you can gimme something based on it? thanks

Comment: Currently, I can see correct glue records so you are right that it took some time to propagate the change.

Comment: Well, the worst problem is the one you don't know about. Thanks anyways bro